# Where / how to store API keys in Google Colabs securely?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-colaboratory

If I share for example a Google Colab ipynb with other I don't want them to be able to access my API keys. In AWS there would be something like SecureString in Parameter Store for Lambdas. Is there something similar to use with Google Colabs? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I now do it like that

```
drive.mount('/content/drive')
with open('testLALALALA.json') as jsonfile:
    KEY_DATA = json.load(jsonfile)


def initialize_analyticsreporting():
  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(KEY_DATA, SCOPES)
  analytics = build('analyticsreporting', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
  return analytics
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save your key in Google Drive. Then mount and load it.

Other people can mount and load their own.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use Google Colab Secrets feature:

[image]

`google.colab.userdata` allows you to get those Secrets and assign to environment variables:

```
import os
from google.colab import userdata

os.environ["AWS_SECRET_KEY"]=userdata.get('AWS_SECRET_KEY')
os.environ["AWS_ACCESS_KEY"]=userdata.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY')
```